# (Jade & Stormpath) Only display certain HTML elements if a specific user visits page

Tags: node.js, express, pug, stormpath

I'm trying to get my first web app ever off the ground so I'm well aware this is a kind of beginner question.

I am using Node, express, and Mongo for the backend with Stormpath providing user login / authentication and jade for views.  The login functionality works fine, It just that I want to hide the 'Upload New Schedule' button for users that are not managers:

```
// app.js

...
app.use(stormPathmiddleware);

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
   res.render('home', {
     title: 'Welcome'
   });
);

app.get('/upload', stormpath.groupsRequired(['Enforced']), function(req, res) {
   res.render('upload', {
      title: 'Upload Excel File'
   });
});
....
```

I have two groups of people that I want using this: managers and everyone else.  So home.jade:

```
html
  head
    title=title
    link(href='//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css', rel='stylesheet')
  body
    div.container
      div.jumbotron
        h1 Hello!

        if user
          p Welcome, #{user.fullName}
          p
          a.btn.btn-primary(href="/upload") Upload New Schedule
          br
          br
          a.btn.btn-primary(href="/logout") Logout
        else
          p Login now to see this weeks schedule. 
          p
            a.btn.btn-primary(href="/login") Login now
```

How can I make jade hide the upload button to people who are not logged in as the first group (managers)? The middleware works great, that is people who are not managers will get an error page if they try to click that button, but I'd rather just hide it.

Comment: Probably something like `if(user.manager)` would be my guess, depending on how do you actually determine if a user is a manager? You can check in your Mongoose Schema definition for your User

Answer (score 0):

what you'll need to do here is:

- Pre-load the permission check you want to do in your route code.
- Pass this into your template.
- Use this variable in your template to display or not display stuff.

Here's how it could work for your use case:

```
app.get('/upload', function(req, res, next) {
  var isManager = false;

  // Search through this user's groups, for any group named 'managers'.
  req.user.getGroups({ name: 'managers' }, function(err, groups) {
    if (err) return next(err);

    // If this user is a member of a 'managers' group, it means
    // this user is a manager.
    if (groups.items && groups.items[0].name === 'managers') {
      isManager = true;
    }

    res.render('upload', {
      title: 'Upload Excel File',
      isManager: isManager  // Pass in the membership information to Jade.
    });
  });
});
```

Now that we've defined a route and passed in the manager information, we can write a Jade file that does something like this:

```
if isManager
  // display html code here for managers
else
  // display NON manager html code here
```

Hopefully this was helpful! I'm the author of this library, and just stumbled across this =)

I'm currently looking at new ways to make this easier in the future, so hopefully it'll be quite a bit simpler in the next big release =)